# Safecracker entry form, specifying categories across multiple pages

Tags: safecracker, categories

I have a multiple page Safecracker form, as there are a number of large category groups that need to be chosen from.
On Page 2, I have a content type select.
On Page 3, I have a topic select.
And, on Page 4, I have a number of selects to reference syllabus documents.

The select fields look like this, that is the categories shown are being filtered by group_id:

```
<select name="category[]" id="select_syll-ac" multiple="multiple" class="multiselect">
          {categories group_id="17"}
                  <option value="{category_id}"{selected}>{category_name}</option>
          {/categories}
</select>
```

Currently, only the options selected on Page 4 are making it to the final entry.
I thought that previously the options selected on page 2 were also being retained.

preserve_checkboxes=“yes” does not fix the behaviour.

Given Pages 2, 3 and 4 are all dealing with categories, do I have to add a hidden select of the category groups on Page 2 and 3 to Page 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to output the already checked categories in order to preserve the selection. You can output those categories in hidden fields in each pages:

```
{categories}
{if '{selected}' != ''}<input type="hidden" name="category[]" value="{category_id}" />{/if}
{/categories}
```

otherwise, on each submit containing the field category[], the categories will be reset to the new form values.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I figured. I was just wondering if there was something I was missing.